# Falcor - Is there a way to iterate a map

Tags: falcor

So far I have found that we can iterate on arrays using `{from: x, to: y}`. Is there a way to iterate on a map?

For example, I have the following map:

```
    companyMap: {
        61: {
            name: 'Apple'
        },
        66: {
            name: 'Microsoft'
        },
        70: {
            name: 'Uber'
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to iterate on this map? Or at least get all the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over a map, you need to first establish a practical (*not theoretical*) maximum for the number of keys you're going to have.

You can't make a call for an unbounded amount of data in Falcor, by design. If there is no practical maximum, it may be best to reconsider how you page through the data in the first place.

For example, if you set the practical maximum at 70 keys, you'll need to make the following request:

```
this.model.get(`companyMap[0..70]['name']`);
```

For those keys that do not exist in the dataset, there will be nothing returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for an arbitrary number of keys. For example the following path set:

```
["companyMap", [61, 66, 70], "name"]
```

returns the names from the 3 companies.